# Tuxguitar - no sound on 22.10

Tags: sound, 22.10, pipewire, tuxguitar

I have always this type of issue when installing a new version of Ubuntu from scratch.
I typically solve by adding some plugins, however I read that 22.10 sports with Pipewire as a new audio server.

Not being an expert my concern is to mess things, is there a clear procedure to make audio working on Tuxguitar?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't have audio on Tuxguitar, I typically solved the issue by installing the alsa plugin, however since 22.10 has a new and different audio server I am concerned to break the system, so I'd like to hear from someone else experience.

Answer (score 0):

### How to fix TuxGuitar no sound output on Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10

Someone has kindly posted these instructions online and they worked for me. See the bottom of this answer for the source. This is what I did:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tuxguitar tuxguitar-fluidsynth
```

Start **TuxGuitar**.

Open the menu `Tools > Plugins`:

- Select `Fluidsynth` output plugin and press `Configure`.
- In the **Soundfonts** tab, press `Add` and browse to your sound font. In my system it was in `/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2`.
- In the **Audio** tab, select `pulseaudio` audio driver.
- Press `OK` to apply the changes.
- Press `Close` to close plugins dialog.

Open the menu `Tools > Settings`:

- Select the **Sound** tab.
- Select the `TuxGuitar Sequencer` midi sequencer.
- Select the `TG Fluidsynth [FluidR3_GM]` midi port.
- Press `OK` and apply the changes.

Finished, now the sound worked for me.

*Source*: https://velenux.wordpress.com/2023/01/21/how-to-install-and-configure-tuxguitar/